# Vue js Custom directive gives parent width smaller then child width in chrome but in safari it gives me both same

Tags: css, vue.js, safari

this code gives parent < child in chrome, but it gives parent = child in safari browser.

```
      bind: function(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
          let parent = el.clientWidth
          let child = el.children[0].clientWidth
          if (!parent || !child) {
            return
          }
          clearInterval(intervalId)
          if (child - parent <= 45) {
            el.classList.remove('table-scroll') // add css class to parent element
          }
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
```

Comment: So whats the question? Do you want to know why ist is like this?

Comment: @jdickel i want to add a scroll to parent element with some condition like if `child - parent <= 45`
it is working fine for chrome but not working for safari as i am getting `child = parent`